# How can I create a relative path in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, href, relative-path

I'm working on a RESTful Rails App in which I need to create a href link to a relative path. The current HTML code inside of a view (with embedded Ruby) I have is simply:

```
a href="/resources/edit/<%= @resource.id %>"
```

When I run my app on my dev server and click on the link, it takes me from http://my.dev.server:2005/blah to http://my.dev.server:2005/resources/edit/34 (for example).

However, when I launch this app on my test server (which mirrors my Prod server), it takes me from http://my.real.server/my_app_name/blah to http://my.real.server/resources/edit/34.

So as you can see, the href relative path removes my app name from the URL on my test server - how can I edit the href tag so that it keeps my app name and then adds the relative path to it?

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Not sure I follow...there is no from and to for a link. When you click on a relative link, all it will do is append the server name in front of the relative URL and navigate to it.

Comment: I thought the relative link appends the current page URL, not just the server name? My issue is that the href I displayed above redirects to my.real.server/resources/edit/34 instead of my.real.server/app_name/resources/edit/34

Comment: You will have to set a base url to my.real.server/app_name if you want to achieve what you are looking to do. If a base URL is not set, the only thing you will get is the server name

Comment: How about you use url helpers. Do `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_resource_path(@resource) %>` This will  do what want. Read more about link_to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: The problem is that this is a HREF tag within a Bootstrap button, so that doesn't work. I just hardcoded the app_name in, so it doesn't matter now. Thanks for the suggestion, though!